# Trying to understand specific IFNA statement using multiple IF statements

Tags: excel-formula

Could someone please explain to me what this Excel formula is assessing:

```
IFNA(IF(OR(S3<>"Complete",AC3<>AD3,AE3<>0),(IF(S3="NA","NA",(VLOOKUP(G3,'FAIR Burn'!$B$3:$M$34,11,FALSE)))),"Complete"),S3)
```

1. For example the first part; (OR(S3<>"Complete",AC3<>AD3,AE3<>0), if this condition is satisfied, what value does it take on?
2. And the second part; (IF(S3="NA","NA",(VLOOKUP(G3,'FAIR Burn'!$B$3:$M$34,11,FALSE)))), what value does it use if satisfied?
3. The last part of the formula references S3. so if the embedded formula in IFNA () is not met, the value in S3 is used?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the first `IF` then you have the condition, then the part that is evaluated if condition = true --> in this case another IF-clause, then "Complete" as the false-part

The inner IF checks for S3 = NA, if true the second part is returned, if false the VLOOKUP is returned.

If the result of the first IF returns NA the formula as whole returns S3.

```vb
IFNA(
    IF ( OR(S3<>"Complete",AC3<>AD3,AE3<>0) ,   
         (
           IF(S3="NA",
              "NA",
              (VLOOKUP(G3,'FAIR Burn'!$B$3:$M$34,11,FALSE))
              )
         ),
         "Complete"
       ),
    S3
)
```

To answer your questions:

1. the second/inner IF-clause will be evaluated
2. IF S3 = "NA" then it returns "NA"
3. if the embedded formula returns NA value of S3 is returned

Comment: Hi Ike. So to clarify, if one of the conditions in the OR statement is evaluated to be True, then the inner IF condition is evaluated?
And if the OR statement is not evaluated to be True, then "Complete" will be used as the value?

Comment: @GusG yes that is the nature of `OR` if any are `TRUE` then it returns `TRUE`.  If you want all to equal `TRUE` before it returns `TRUE` then use `AND`

Comment: Thanks Ike and Scott

Comment: Just a follow-up question; what if Vlookup does not find a match, then what value is returned? If it returns NA, then the value of S3 is used as part of the IFNA evaluation?

Comment: I would suppose so - yes. And as VLookup is used when S3 <> NA then the result of the formula will be the value of S3